# Coin Toss in a square Probabilty of breaking even

Tags: probability

A player tosses a fair coin into a board filled with $5 \times 5\ cm$ tiles and the host pays the player a certain amount of money for each coin that lands in the square. I have figured out the probability of the coin landing inside the individual tiles.  But what is intriguing me is how much the host needs to pay the player for every coin that falls within the lines of the tiles.  The player is using 2 dollar coins to toss.  The probability of the 2 dollar coin falling inside the tile is $34.8\%$.

I have figured out this question as $6 for every coin falling in the tile. But my method is very weak, and I would think unreliable. Hope you can help.

this is a problem that has been bugging me for many years.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the $2$-dollar coin you're referring to is the Australian, for which the probability you give would be correct.

In general, if a gambler's stake is $\ s\ $, he or she has a probability $\ p\ $ of winning the bet, and the host pays $\ w s\ $ when the bet wins, then the gambler's expected gain is
$$
wsp  - (1-p)s= s(wp + p-1)\ .
$$
The payout is *fair* (i.e. neither the gambler nor his host's expected gain is positive) when the value of this expression is $0$—that is, $\ w=\frac{1-p}{p}\ $. In your case this would be $\ \frac{0.652}{0.348}\approx1.874\ $.  So if you require the bet to be fair, then the host would need to pay $\ 2\times 1.874\approx3.75 $ dollars for each winning coin (not including the winning coin itself, which is also returned to the gambler).

Comment: What method are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question.  According to the [strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law), the gambler's average gain per toss in the long run is equal to his probabilistic expected gain for each toss.  The amount I've given is what the host needs to pay to ensure that this is zero.  In practice, of course, hosts of such games will typically pay *less than* this, to ensure that they actually make a *profit* in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the \$$2$ is lost if it lands on a line, then break even is achieved if the payout is $2\cdot \frac{.642}{.348} = \$3.75$

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail? I’m slightly confused as where the fraction came in.

Comment: And also, what method is this called?

Comment: My mistake on the fraction; see revision. It's just an equality; the probability of winning times the amount won must equal the probability of losing times the amount lost to break even. Hence $2\cdot .652 = 3.75\cdot .348$